# Unconventional Idea - How do I convert an array to a Class?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, search, autohotkey

First of all, I'm a novice programmer. I learned AutoHotkey script, a bunch of c# and some or c++. My question is not language or syntax specific, but more of a concept. I'll start by explaining the situation (any code should be interpreted similar to psuedo code).

My latest project is an instant messenger sort of program, with a server and a client. They work as follows:

### Server

- Assign client info into 3 different arrays (I don't like this)

  - NewConnection[skt], userNick[nick], nickFromSocket[skt]

### Client

- Send messages to the server > server receives > server responds > client receives
  and logs messages to chat log.

You probably have already noticed that the array 'userNick' uses the users actual nickname in replace of the traditional index number (userNick[index]). This is important and works like this:

```
// New user has connected
skt  = WINSOCK_getSkt()
NewConnection[skt]  // Simple to parse with a loop: NewConnection.MaxIndex()

// Receive new user's nickname
skt  = WINSOCK_getSkt()
nick = WINSOCK_getNick()
userNick[nick]      = nick
nickFromSocket[skt] = nick
```

The theory behind assigning the user's nickname twice is to avoid using a loop to parse the arrays. This is simple and can be achieved because when the client sends a message to the server, the server can see the socket number (which is unique to each user), with that variable, I can instantly get the user's nickname from 2 short lines:

```
// Get user's nickname
skt  = WINSOCK_getSkt()
nick = nickFromSocket[skt]
```

I hope everything is clear till now.

### Question

How can I convert all this to a class, yet retain the speed of getting data from an array? I know a class would be much simpler to work with, and more logical, but I'm afraid of the efficiency of the class when there are more and more users to parse through. Is there an equivalent in objects/classes? Thank you kindly for your time to read through this.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and/or incorrect. (if it's pseudo-code, please say so).

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil", Donald Knuth

Comment: @SidharthMudgal "Changing things that already work isn't always for efficiency purposes", Me.

Comment: Ahh, excellent words of wisdom everyone, thanks! Sometimes I get paralyzed, can't move forward in development, all because I'm too busy being worried about how to make my code efficient. I guess that is not good.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need a class. Like

```
class User
{
    public string Nick { get; set; }
    public Socket Sock { get; set; }  // not sure about this type
    ...
}
```

And then, depending on your actual needs, use a `List<User>` and/or `Dictionary<Connection, User>`.

Comment: Thank you Henk, but I don't think my question was very clear, so that's my fault. The main question, basically, is how to retrieve a user's nick from socket and vice versa /whithout/ parsing, but using a class.